# Does HCL OneTest Data generate the data for auditable fields when a user imports a schema from database?

Tags: schema, audit

When I import a schema or sample data set from a database, then does HCL OneTest Data generate the data for auditable fields, such as INSERTED TIME, UPDATE TIME) in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, HCL OneTest Data does not support the data insertion to fields with the DateTime data type.